# Automatically Returning to First Page of Results with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat with multiple filters and pagination. The issue arises when a user is on page 5 when a filter is applied that yields results that do not extend to 5 pages. In this case, the current page remains at 5 but the list is blank. I'd like to figure out a way to have the pager automatically return to the first page when any new filter is applied so the list is always present.

Here is the ng-repeat in question:

```
<div class="task low" ng-repeat="(key, candidate) in candidates | filter:greaterThanGpa | filter:schoolNameFilter | filter:majorFilter | filter:classYearFilter | filter:diversityFilter | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: anytime a filter is modified, set currentPage to zero.

Comment: Thanks for replying @robertking what event or hook can I apply that code to?

Comment: you could use a $watch on the filter variables. Alternatively whatever button they click to adjust the filter could also reset the currentPage to zero.

Comment: Thanks! Set a new function to trigger on ng-change since the filters are applied as the inputs are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a `$watch` on the filter variables. Alternatively whatever button they click to adjust the filter could also reset the `currentPage` to zero.